# Cron job to delete old posts

Tags: mysql, cron

What's wrong with this cron job? It's not executing.

```
mysql -u user -p password -h host db -e "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE DATE < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 DAY)"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you thing there is something wrong?

Comment: Because i set it to execute in five minutes, and it's been over 30 minutes now @Jens

Comment: Maybe the command is not found. Which OS you are running?

Comment: What happens when you add the missing terminating semi-colon (`;`) to the query?

Comment: What exactly is the crontab entry? Have you looked in your cron logs?

Comment: @Jens Linux on shared hosting

Comment: Have you access to `/var/log/syslog`? if you have an error in your cron job, you should see here what happends. I guess you have to add the path before `mysql`

Comment: @MarcusAdams adding the semicolon does not make it work :-(

Comment: Keep the semi-colon because it won't work without it. Check your error log. There's not enough information in your question for us to diagnose the issue other than your syntax error.

Comment: Please where can I find the cron logs? I can't find the /var folder

Answer (score 0):

When entering queries via command-line, don't forget the terminating semi-colon (`;`):

```
mysql -u user -p password -h host db -e "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE DATE < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 DAY);"
```